# EF: Loading Related Entities Lazy way dont work

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Where am I wrong? I receive `NullReferenceExeption` in the Navigation Property `Events`.  It is marked as `virtual` and `LazyLoadingEnabled` is explicitly allowed.

program code:

```
using (var db = new Db())
{
    var person = new Person();
    person.Name = "bla bla";
    db.Persons.Add(person);
    person.Events = new List<Event>(1);
    person.Events.Add(new Event() { Description = "ABC", At = DateTime.Now });
    db.SaveChanges();
}

using (var db = new Db())
{
    var person = db.Persons.First();

    Console.WriteLine(person.Events == null);  //Output: True
    Console.WriteLine(person.Events.Count);    //System.NullReferenceException
}
```

Explicit loading works:

```
var person = db.Persons.First();
db.Entry(person).Collection(p => p.Events).Load();
Console.WriteLine(person.Events == null);  //Output: False
Console.WriteLine(person.Events.Count);    //1
```

Classes structure:

```
class Db : DbContext
{
    public Db()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Db>());
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

class Person
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

class Event
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime At { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i think your foreign key relation is not correct

Comment: It might have something to do with the version of EF - have you updated it lately? Could you post the version you are using?

Comment: @Default when i creating entities i will add a property for Person in Event specifying that Event has a relationship with Person and also change the List<Event> to Icollection<Event>

Comment: @frebinfrancis, It is not necessary to do so, as far as I knew, but I tried, and I've updated the question, the same result.

Comment: did you check that the foreign keys(indexes) are created for both table in SQL?

Comment: did you try to call like person.Events or use include to add the object collection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model classes **need to be public** to be lazy-loaded. Change `class Person` and `class Event` to be `public class Person` etc, and your test program will start working.

Answer (score -1):

It's simple.

Create default constructor in Person class and init Events collection like

```
public Person()
{
   Events = new HashSet<Event>();
}
```

And add virtual property with type Person to Event class

EDIT:
In EF codefirst you responsible for collection initialization and EF responsible for filling this collection from database

Comment: I tried that before I asked. The result: Event is not null BUT EMPTY.

Comment: Maybe this comment will be helpfull [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322501/ef-loading-related-entities/28322796?noredirect=1#comment44992926_28322501), or you just not have data in database

Comment: also, if i load explcity `db.Entry(person).Collection(p => p.Events).Load();`, its work without constructor initalizer.

Comment: @Richard, i tested. the collection its empty (person.Events.Count = 0).

Comment: **Conclusion**: in a lazy loading, collection can be null. the Entity Framework Proxy initialize the collection. So the answer is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `new Person()` with `context.Persons.Create()`.

This will give you an Entity Framework Person Proxy, rather than a `Person`. This proxy class derives from `Person`, but has its `Events` property overridden with Lazy loading logic.

However this does not take away from the main problem in your code. Which is the reusage of a Context. Which you aren't meant to do.

Comment: my question refer the second `using` section. that `Person` class created by EF

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing wrong with your code: if you do a `Count` on a null collection, you will always get `NullReferenceException` - that's nothing to do with Entity Framework, that's .NET.

There is a difference between a null collection and an empty collection.

Now, if you want to avoid such `NullReferenceException` exceptions, you can always initiate the list in the default constructor, as in:

```
class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        Events = new List<Event>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: in a lazy loading, collection can be null. the Entity Framework Proxy initialize the collection.

Comment: I know it can be null. Even if with lazy loading off it can be null - unless if you initialize it in the default constructor, which I and others have indicated. I'm afraid the question was not clear: you were asking why you have `NullReferenceExeption`. The reason is because the collection is null. It sounds like you should have asked why is the collection null.

Comment: I realized, sorry if I was not clear on the question. Mentioned the `NullReferenceExeption` error was made just to show most clearly the fact that the lazy loading does not work.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
          Events = new List<Event>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{    
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime At { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
}
```

You need to initialize any Colection navigation properity using the same type of the collection and NOT 'HashSet', like this.

Comment: in a lazy loading, collection can be null. the Entity Framework Proxy initialize the collection.